# make selected menu active change the background of menu item selected with activeclass

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i have this side bar with some menu items when i click on a menu item link i want to set `.listItemActiveclass` it so it becomes the active class  and the background colour changes of the menu intecating it is selected

```
export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  render() {
    function hideBar() {
      var sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
      sidebar.classList.remove("show");
      sidebar.classList.add("hide");
    }
    return (
      <>
        <div className="sidebar" style={styles.header}>
          <a class="close-icon" href="#" onClick={hideBar}>
            &#10006;
          </a>
          <img src={Logo} alt="" />

          <ul style={styles.lists}>
            <Link to="/doctor">
              <li activeClassName="active" style={styles.listItemActive}>
                <div>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faThLarge}
                    style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div> Overview</div>
              </li>
            </Link>

            <Link to="/dappointment">
              <li activeClassName="active" style={styles.listItem}>
                {" "}
                <div>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faBriefcaseMedical}
                    style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div> Appointments</div>
              </li>
            </Link>

            <Link to="/dall_clients">
              <li style={styles.listItem}>
                <div>
                  <i className="fa fa-user" style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}></i>
                </div>
                <div> All Clients List</div>
              </li>
            </Link>

            <Link to="#">
              <li style={styles.listItem}>
                <div>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faSms}
                    style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>Messages</div>
              </li>
            </Link>
          </ul>
          <div
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              bottom: "3rem",
              left: "30px",
              width: "15%",
            }}
          >
            <div style={{ marginTop: "3rem" }}>
              <button
                style={{
                  color: "#fff",
                  textDecoration: "none",
                  background: "transparent",
                  border: "none",
                }}
              >
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCog} style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }} />
                Settings
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  header: {
    background: "#ffffff1c 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box",
    padding: "2rem",
    minHeight: "100%",
    width: "20%",
    margin: "0",
    color: "white",
  },
  lists: {
    marginTop: "5rem",
    color: "#fff",
    paddingLeft: "0",
    listStyle: "none",
  },
  listItem: {
    background: "transparent",
    padding: "10px 50px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    display: "flex",
  },
  listItemActive: {
    background: "#6a0f4b",
    padding: "10px 50px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    display: "flex",
  },
};
```

i have this side bar with some menu items when i click on a menu item link i want to set .listItemActiveclass it so it becomes the active class i cant use bootstrap beouse i have done my project without bootstap

Comment: According to the react-router documentation [`activeClassName` is a `<NavLink>`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/activeclassname-string) property. Why have you added it to the list items?

Comment: i am new to react i dont have much knowlage about it